# Make cropping of extremely large GeoTIFF files faster

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, performance

I have a 70GB GeoTIFF file, already LZW-compressed and tiled. Accessing a small area of it in QGIS takes more than a minute. Cropping a 10000*10000 patch from it with `gdalwarp` takes several minutes.

How can I make access to this image faster? Is there a way of doing that while keeping the file whole?

Comment: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: As a verification, add relevant parts of gdalinfo report. Projection is not interesting in you do not warp by the same.

Comment: It's possible that the compression and tiling has increased the extraction time. Splitting a large raster into mosaic tiles can sometimes be a better solution.